# What is purpose of closing BufferedReader class? Does it affect time / memory (if how)?

Tags: java

codeforces contest 355 Q_A by blackhorse21

```
public class A_VanyaAndFence {
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
    int n,h;
    n=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    h=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    st=new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
    //int arr[]=new int[n];
    int cnt=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int a=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        if(a>h){
            cnt+=2;
        }
        else
            cnt++;
    }
    System.out.println(cnt);
}
```

This code took 155ms,20100 KB

```
public class A_VanyaAndFence {
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
    int n,h;
    n=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    h=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    st=new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
    //int arr[]=new int[n];
    int cnt=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int a=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        if(a>h){
            cnt+=2;
        }
        else
            cnt++;
    }
    System.out.println(cnt);
    br.close();
}
```

}

This code took 124ms,20100 KB

Why?

Comment: It's quite standard to use resources when you need them, and free them when you no longer need them. Your test is also quite naive, so you shouldn't draw conclusions based on it.

Comment: @Kayaman. The question is still interesting though because it asks why we should do a thing that we so often take for granted should be done. The answer is simple: resources are finite, but not always easy for a beginner to understand.

Comment: I would argue that you *shouldn't* close that `BufferedReader`, because this has the effect of closing `System.in`. You shouldn't close a stream if you didn't open it.

Comment: If you asking why it took less time, I'd point out it appears you are looking at a single run of each of these programs - run time can be affected by a lot of things, including load on the CPU at the time. This is why most performance benchmarks do a number of trials and use statistics (or in very simple cases, averaging) to get a general run-time in different scenarios to compare. A single run is often subject to too many variables to allow a meaningful comparison - I'd recommend averaging multiple runs and seeing if the result matches

Answer (score -1):

Even though the impact might not be too significant, when the text being read is not too extensive. There has to be an impact on memory primarily, and time secondarily, especially when the text being read is massive. close() method not only closes the stream, but also releases the system resources associated with the BufferReader / Reader class implementation.

File descriptor is a resource in the operating system, which will get released once close() is called on the BufferReader . In the latest versions of Java, garbage collector runs every now and then, and should call the close() mehtod for you and dispose off the abandoned file descriptor. But untill then, the poor guy will be hanging around the corner.

Lets say you were initializing BufferReader objects inside a large loop, and not closing the same within the loop. Your loop might pick up the abandoned file descriptors before the garbage collector does its job.
Its also a good programming practice because once the stream has been closed, other BufferReader / Reader methods will through IOExceptions (another close() method will do nothing).

Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#close()

That being said, I myself worked on an extensive project where closing BufferReader for each instance became difficult, and I did avoid it on several occasions.  It didn’t have any impact worth noticing on the output and program execution. BufferReader objects will eventually get discarded by the garbage collector. Most real world applications may be satisfied with the performance of the garbage collection and not show any significant impact in terms of time and memory.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Neither `BufferedReader` nor its superclass implement `finalize()`; so the stream is not being cleaned up by that being garbage collected (and you shouldn't rely on `finalize()` ever being called anyway). So this is a dangerous strategy to advocate.

Comment: In 3/4th of my comment I'm not suggesting using Garbage collection as a strategy, in fact I'm suggesting that close() should be called if you have instantiated BufferReader as a good practice. When you suggest that you shouldn't close BufferReader as it also closes input stream, what do you think happens to the system resources associated with the BufferReader?

Comment: "Most real world applications would be more than satisfied with the performance of the garbage collection" sounds a lot like recommending relying on GC as a strategy.

Comment: "When you suggest that you shouldn't close BufferReader as it also closes input stream" I am suggesting that you shouldn't close a `BufferedReader` *if you didn't open the input stream yourself*, the reason being that the person who passed it to you can't know that you have closed it, without attempting an IO operation and catching the failure.

Comment: I meant to explain why it explicitly doesn't seem to make a big difference if not closed. Read the first 3-4 paras as well. There's no "I recommend" anywhere. But a clear mention of what a good practice would be.

Comment: In his example he is initializing BufferReader. So closing it is recommended. And close method closes both BufferReader and InputStreamReader.

Comment: *And* `System.in`. `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));`: the innermost stream here is `System.in`, which is opened by the JVM, not the user code.

Comment: Yes, but InputStreamReader and BufferReader streams have been opened by the user using the System.in. So the streams have to be closed ideally to release associated system resources. Anyways, this is my point and I appreciate yours. I'm in no way recommending letting GC handle it. I recommend using close() when the stream has been opened by the user for reasons mentioned in my initial answer.

Comment: @AndyTurner Whether they implement `finalize()` is irrelevant. At the bottom of the woodpile there is a `FileInputStream`, which does implement `finalize()`. But I agree that this stream should not be closed anyway.